# Magento 1.9.1.0 Front controller reached 100 router match iterations Error

Tags: php, magento

I'm on magento 1.9.1.0 - once or twice a day Magento throws an "Front controller reached 100 router match iterations"

I've added the below code to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php

```
Mage::log('----Matching routers------------------------------');
Mage::log('Total ' . count($this->_routers) . ': ' . implode(', ', array_keys($this->_routers)));
while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++<100) {
Mage::log('- Iteration ' . $i);
$requestData = array(
    'path_info' => $request->getPathInfo(),
    'module' => $request->getModuleName(),
    'action' => $request->getActionName(),
    'controller' => $request->getControllerName(),
    'controller_module' => $request->getControllerModule(),
    'route' => $request->getRouteName()
);

$st = '';
foreach ($requestData as $key => $val) {
    $st .= "[{$key}={$val}]";
}
Mage::log('Request: ' . $st);
foreach ($this->_routers as $name => $router) {
    if ($router->match($this->getRequest())) {
        Mage::log('Matched by "' . $name . '" router, class ' . get_class($router));
        break;
    }
}
}
```

This gives me the following system.log:

```
2015-04-30T07:40:14+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T07:40:14+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 5: admin, standard, cms, neotheme_blog, default
2015-04-30T07:40:14+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T07:40:14+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=catalog/category/view/id/394][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T07:40:14+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T07:40:14+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 5: admin, standard, cms, neotheme_blog, default
2015-04-30T07:40:14+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T07:40:14+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=catalog/product/view/id/99][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T07:40:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T07:40:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 5: admin, standard, cms, neotheme_blog, default
2015-04-30T07:40:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T07:40:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/onestepcheckout/ajax/set_methods_separate/][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T07:40:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "standard" router, class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
2015-04-30T07:40:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "standard" router, class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
2015-04-30T07:40:20+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T07:40:20+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 5: admin, standard, cms, neotheme_blog, default
2015-04-30T07:40:20+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T07:40:20+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=catalog/product/view/id/184/category/457][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T07:40:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "standard" router, class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
2015-04-30T07:40:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T07:40:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 5: admin, standard, cms, neotheme_blog, default
2015-04-30T07:40:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T07:40:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=catalog/category/view/id/356][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T07:40:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "standard" router, class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
2015-04-30T07:40:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "standard" router, class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
2015-04-30T07:40:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T07:40:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 5: admin, standard, cms, neotheme_blog, default
2015-04-30T07:40:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T07:40:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/klantenservice/][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T07:40:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "cms" router, class Mage_Cms_Controller_Router
2015-04-30T07:40:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 2
2015-04-30T07:40:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/klantenservice/][module=cms][action=view][controller=page][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T07:40:58+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T07:40:58+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 5: admin, standard, cms, neotheme_blog, default
2015-04-30T07:40:58+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T07:40:58+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5lY2NlbGxlbnRlLm5sL21lbGl0dGEtb25kZXJob3Vkc3NldD9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,/product/99/form_key/7ECJFLVVgHoL7qMo/][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
```

And that goes on and on.

How do I fix this?

If you need any more information please let me know.

@Christoffer: Disabling the nBlog results in the following system.log:

```
2015-04-30T13:04:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T13:04:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 4: admin, standard, cms, default
2015-04-30T13:04:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T13:04:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T13:05:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T13:05:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 4: admin, standard, cms, default
2015-04-30T13:05:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T13:05:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T13:05:11+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T13:05:11+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 4: admin, standard, cms, default
2015-04-30T13:05:11+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T13:05:11+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/api/][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T13:05:11+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "standard" router, class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 4: admin, standard, cms, default
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/api/][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "standard" router, class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 4: admin, standard, cms, default
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/api/index/index/][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): ----Matching routers------------------------------
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Total 4: admin, standard, cms, default
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 1
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/api/index/index/][module=][action=][controller=][controller_module=][route=]
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "standard" router, class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
2015-04-30T13:05:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "standard" router, class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
```

Comment: Try after flushing cache folder

Comment: That's the point - you have to keep flushing the cache folder several times a day. That's not a real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try and inactivate the nBlog extension and if that fixes the problem, look into it's routing code to see what it does wrong.

Could the problem be narrowed down to a specific type of URL's?  If it's on blog URL's you get this problem, that solidifies my suspicion.

It's far more likely that an added routing class from a third party extension is responsible than that the core stuff is.

**Edit**

Perhaps this module can help you:
https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug

Comment: I've edited my question with the results from your suggestion.

Comment: None of those logs actually seem to have captured the problem. You need to narrow it down by finding specific URL's or scenarios where you get this error. Edited answer with link to module-fix you could try.

Comment: Thanks I´ll try it out tomorow!

Comment: How did that work out for you Feggel? I'm always curious to see if I've helped people!

Comment: Hey, thanks I tried your suggestions. With the nBlog extension disables we weren't getting the errors anymore! Solved it, thanks!